# optimize switch code to function args call

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Im using the following code that working OK.

```
  _handleIn: function(Filecontent, config) {
            var oExtendedHTML = Filecontent;
            switch (config.action) {
                case 'new':
                    oExtended = this._crElement(Filecontent, config);
                    break;
                case 'upd':
                    oExtended = this._updlement(oExtended, config);
                    break;
            }
            return oExtended;
        },
```

Since I new to JS and I want to learn more I read that the switch sometimes can be change to this pseudo coe:

This

```
function actions(key, args){
  switch(key){ 
    case: 'foo':
      return doFoo(args);
      break;
    case: 'bar':
      return doBar(args);
      break;
    case: 'baz':
      return doBaz(args);
      break
  }
}

var value = actions(keyargs);

// To This



 var actions = {
      foo: function doFoo(){...},
      bar: function doBar(){...},
      baz: function doBaz(){...}
    };

    var value = actions[key](args);.
```

my question is how can I change my code to this? not sure how to pass the key and args, Im using requirejs AMD module.

Comment: The two examples you show aren't directly comparable, and in my opinion trying to change your code to work like the example with the `actions` object doesn't make sense. Sometimes `switch` is the best choice. In your case you can simplify the switch by having the first case just `return  this._createElement(Filecontent, config);` and the second case return its value. Then you wouldn't need the `break` statements or the `oExtended` variable.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Thanks but not sure how to change it can you please provide your example as answer.thank you!

Comment: Cached object literal (Look Up Table) method is much faster in Chrome but Switch-case is faster in Firefox. Check it out here https://jsperf.com/switch-vs-object-literal-vs-module/28

Comment: @Redu - can you please provide example as answer I can I use my code in lookup table? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// your function without `switch`
var _handleInnerElement = {
    _createElement: function(){
        alert('create');
    },
    _updateElement: function(){
        alert('update');
    },
    // you can use strings also
    'new': function(fileContent, config) {
        return this._createElement(fileContent, config);
    },
    upd: function(fileContent, config) {
        return this._updateElement(fileContent, config);
    }
}
// some variables to work with
var config = {
    action: 'new',
    some_data: 123
}
var someFileContent = {};
// usage
_handleInnerElement[config.action](someFileContent, config);
```

Comment: HI Thank you, Im inside module of require.js AMD, how should I use then code then? and the var dont need to be changed to something like _handleInnerElement :function(someFileContent, config) {?